# Auto wordWrap to the window VSC

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to auto word wrap all files to the window. In sublime this is simple with `auto` however, in VSC I have three options:

```
editor.wordWrap
editor.wordWrapColumn
editor.wrappingIndent
```

My issue is that no matter what settings I use I am unable to wrap the text to the window. There is about a 3 inch gap on 15in monitor from where the text ends to the edge of the window. I want to be able to move the window by snapping to any edge and my words wrap automatically no matter what size the window is - if you have used sublime you will understand this situation.

```json
"word_wrap": "auto",
"wrap_width": 0
```

Thanks for your help. I'm guessing this is a simple step but I am very new to VSC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following settings, the VSCode should always wrap at the Window's edge:

```json
"editor.wordWrap": "bounded",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 9999
```

`"bounded"` is documented as:

> wrap at minimum of viewport and `editor.wordWrapColumn`

Since `wordWrapColumn` is still respected in bounded mode, and the default of 80 is rather low, you basically need to set that to something "unlimited" to get the desired behavior.

[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work. It's almost like the max `editor.wordWrapColumn` is 80. Anything past 80 and the text just stays the same, I still have the 2-3 inch open space - just an unused large gap on my screen. I've tried manipulating the setting in many different ways. It might be something with a theme or additional plugin I have. I will play around with it some more and report back if I get it to work.

Comment: Hm, strange... that's with latest VSCode (1.23.1)? Two things to verify would be that `"editor.wordWrapColumn"` is only specified once in `settings.json` and that you don't have workspace specific settings overriding the global ones or anything like that.

Comment: just a quick update: I had a markdown package overriding the settings and a workspace setting. Anyway, it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: 1.27.1 Word Wrap is OFF yet still wraps at the edge of viewport.